# Extending WP_Customize_Media_Control to return filename

Tags: php, theme-customizer

Is there a Wordpress "correct" way to extend WP_Customize_Media_Control to return the filename instead of attachment ID to the wp.customize preview function? I am using the media control to save a font file which I would like to update in the preview on change.

```
class myUploadControl extends WP_Customize_Media_Control {


    public $required = array();

    public function returnData($return) {

         return 'filename.ttf';

    }


 }
```

I'm looking for something where I can tap into like the above and return the filename to wp.customize instead of the ID.

I have noticed that WP_Customize_Image_Control does indeed return the filename instead of the ID, but this is only for images.

Comment: are you trying to save the filename instead of the ID? Or are you trying to display the image? Have you tried using the standard attachment functions to retrieve the URL/filename?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain great. I'm not processing an image - it's a font file. I am happy saving the ID, but would like to pass the filename into the javascript on change of the field so that I can update my CSS in the preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have noticed that WP_Customize_Image_Control does indeed return the
>   filename instead of the ID, but this is only for images.

That's because the class extends `WP_Customize_Upload_Control` which has the type set to `upload`:

```php
class WP_Customize_Upload_Control extends WP_Customize_Media_Control {
    public $type          = 'upload';
    public $mime_type     = '';
    ...
}
```

And for Customizer controllers using the above class, the JavaScript controller is `wp.customize.UploadControl` which saves the file URL instead of the attachment ID.

So if you want to save the URL instead of the ID, then you could either:

1. Extend `WP_Customize_Upload_Control`:

   ```php
   class myUploadControl extends WP_Customize_Upload_Control {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Or when you add the control, pass an instance of `WP_Customize_Upload_Control`:

   ```php
   $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Upload_Control( $wp_customize, 'your_setting', array(
       'label'   => 'Label Here',
       'section' => 'section_id',
       ...
   ) ) );
   ```

   Note: `$wp_customize` is an instance of the `WP_Customize_Manager` class.

But if you have to save the ID, but need to get the URL dynamically in JavaScript, then you could for example use `wp.apiRequest()` to make an API request to `/wp/v2/media/<media ID>`:

```js
wp.customize( 'your_setting', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( to ) {
        wp.apiRequest( { path: '/wp/v2/media/' + to } )
            .then( function ( s ) {
                console.log( s.source_url ); // logs the full URL to the file
                // do your thing
            } );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response. In truth I couldn't see the wood from the trees, and just performing an ajax request to retrieve the filename is such a simple solution. Thanks again.